# Is there an equivalent to Promise.race() in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm facing this problem where I want to run two functions at once, use the result of whichever one that completes first, and discard the other one immediately.

What would the best practice be to accomplish this in Java?

Comment: There is `CompletableFuture::anyOf` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#anyOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-

Comment: Thanks, that seems valid!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
```

class HelloWorld {

```
public static String awaitRace(CompletableFuture<String> promise1,CompletableFuture<String> promise2)throws Exception{

    while(true){

        if(promise1.isDone()){

            promise2.cancel(true);

            return promise1.get();

        }

        if(promise2.isDone()){

            promise1.cancel(true);

            return promise2.get();

        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   

    

    CompletableFuture<String> promise1 = new CompletableFuture<String>();

   

    promise1 = promise1.supplyAsync(()->{

      

       for(int i=0;i<100;i++){

           System.out.print("HEAVY_1");

       }

      

       return "Result1";

    });

   

    CompletableFuture<String> promise2 = new CompletableFuture<String>();

   

    promise2 = promise2.supplyAsync(()->{

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){

          System.out.print("HEAVY_2");

       }

      

       return "Result2";

    });

    try{

    String result = awaitRace(promise1,promise2);

    System.out.println("First Completed  :"+result);

    }

    catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println(e);

    }

   

    

    System.out.println("Hello, World!");

}
```

This is my own implementation apart from this we have anyOf from completable future itself